# UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext shows EXC_BAD_Access

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, image-capture

I am creating a PDF file that consists of multiple screenshot, but I am facing a problem while extracting images from multiple views. I have a mutable Array which consist of views from a view controller named as "pdfViews"

```
var pdfViews : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
```

and then I am adding view

```
self.pdfViews.addObject(generateAllComponents(kpiName))
```

The `generateAllComponenets(:)` method creates an object of the required view controller and returns the view of that view controller.

And finally I try to convert these views into images and put those images inside an array.

```
for var i = 0 ; i < pdfViews.count; i++
{  
    var currentView = pdfViews.objectAtIndex(i) as! UIView
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(currentView.frame.size)
    currentView.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
    UIGraphicsPushContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
    var image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() as UIImage

    tempImageArray.addObject(image);

}
```

It throws an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. But if I pass only one view i.e, if `pdfViews` has only 1 object then it works absolutely fine. But whenever I go with two objects in the `pdfViews` mutable array, it shows an error like this:

> The Views to be added in pdfViews mutable array also fetches some data
>   from server.

Plus when I tried pass an array of `UIImageViews` as `pdfViews` it also worked fine.
But whenever I go with an array of views it throws this error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :) When you post a question, please make sure that you actually ask a question. From what you've written, I don't know what your question is. Thanks!

Comment: My question over here is how can I create different Images so that I can add them on pdf file..... Using the above strategy I am able to convert only one view but when it comes to multiple views it throws an error of EXC_BAD_ACCESS . I just want to know how can I get Images of different views stored in the array pdfViews